# Haskell formatting and displaying data

Tags: database, haskell, formatting

I'm struggling to display information and format them into separate lines given a database in Haskell..below is what I'm currently using..

```
type Title = String
type Actor = String
type Cast = [Actor]
type Year = Int
type Fan = String
type Fans = [Fan]
type Period = (Year, Year)
type Film = (Title, Cast, Year, Fans)
type Database = [Film]

testDatabase :: Database
testDatabase = [("Casino Royale", ["Daniel Craig", "Eva Green", "Judi Dench"], 2006,          ["Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"]),
("Cowboys & Aliens", ["Harrison Ford", "Daniel Craig", "Olivia Wilde"], 2011, ["Bill", "Jo", "Garry", "Kevin", "Olga", "Liz"]),     
    ("Catch Me If You Can", ["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Tom Hanks"], 2002, ["Zoe", "Heidi", "Jo", "Emma", "Liz", "Sam", "Olga", "Kevin", "Tim"])
```

The above is the example database - and the ultimate goal is to write a function "displayAllFilms" which outputs this:

Casino Royale, Daniel Craig, Eva Green, Judi Dench, 2006, 5

Cowboys & Aliens, Harrison Ford, Daniel Craig, Olivia Wilde, 2011, 6

Note: the formating matters, and each film is dispalyed along with its information on seperate lines and the NUMBER of fans at the end and not a list of the fans.

This is my attempt to solving this problem -

```
displayAllFilms :: [Film] -> String -> String
displayAllFilms [] filmString = filmString
displayAllFilms ((Title cast year fans _):films) filmString = displayAllFilms films (filmString ++ title ++ "\n" ++ (show cast) ++ "\n" ++ (show year) ++ "\n")
```

But it doesn't seem to compile but I cant seem to find anything wrong with my code...Is is a Type error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of mistakes:

```
testDatabase :: Database
testDatabase = [("Casino Royale", ["Daniel Craig", "Eva Green", "Judi Dench"], 2006,          ["Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"]),
    -- indentation should be consistent - this next line was too far left:
    ("Cowboys & Aliens", ["Harrison Ford", "Daniel Craig", "Olivia Wilde"], 2011, ["Bill", "Jo", "Garry", "Kevin", "Olga", "Liz"]),     
    ("Catch Me If You Can", ["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Tom Hanks"], 2002, ["Zoe", "Heidi", "Jo", "Emma", "Liz", "Sam", "Olga", "Kevin", "Tim"])]
```

and you forgot a close bracket `]` at the end of that list.

```
displayAllFilms :: [Film] -> String -> String
displayAllFilms [] filmString = filmString
displayAllFilms ((title,cast,year,fans):films) filmString = displayAllFilms films (filmString ++ title ++ "\n" ++ (show cast) ++ "\n" ++ (show year) ++ "\n")
```

Here you had `(Title cast year fans)` when you meant `(title,cast,year,fans)`.

Haskell is case sensitive, and the capitals would mean `Title` was a constructor, but you mean it to be a variable.
Because your `Film` type is a tuple, you need the commas here to be a tuple as well.

### Getting the output right

Now that gives you output of

```
putStrLn $ displayAllFilms testDatabase "=========="
==========Casino Royale
["Daniel Craig","Eva Green","Judi Dench"]
2006
Cowboys & Aliens
["Harrison Ford","Daniel Craig","Olivia Wilde"]
2011
Catch Me If You Can
["Leonardo DiCaprio","Tom Hanks"]
2002
```

Now that doesn't match your required output,

```
Casino Royale, Daniel Craig, Eva Green, Judi Dench, 2006, 5
```

because there are newlines instead of commas, and brackets you don't want.

```
listStuff:: [String] -> String -> String
listStuff strings separator = concat [string++separator| string <-strings]
```

Here I've used list comprehension to make a list of strings with separators at the end, then `concat` to join them together. You'll get a spare `", "` at the end, but that's OK because we need one between the cast and the year.

Now we can put it together, using `length fans` to show the number of fans.

```
displayAllFilms' :: [Film] -> String -> String
displayAllFilms' [] filmString = filmString
displayAllFilms' ((title,cast,year,fans):films) filmString = 
       displayAllFilms' films (filmString ++ "\n" ++ title ++ ", " ++ listStuff cast ", " ++ (show year) ++ ", " ++ show (length fans))
```

which tests out as

```
>putStrLn $ displayAllFilms' testDatabase ""

Casino Royale, Daniel Craig, Eva Green, Judi Dench, 2006, 5
Cowboys & Aliens, Harrison Ford, Daniel Craig, Olivia Wilde, 2011, 6
Catch Me If You Can, Leonardo DiCaprio, Tom Hanks, 2002, 9
```

### Clean up the code a bit

I don't think `displayAllFilms` needs to be recursive - we could reuse `listStuff` but there's a library function that does more what we want. If you search on hoogle for `[String] -> String -> String` you get these results http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=[String]+-%3E+String+-%3E+String and the second one, `intercalate` is handy:

```
> intercalate "_" ["Hello","Mum,","how","are","you?"]
"Hello_Mum,_how_are_you?"
```

You have to put

```
import Data.List
```

at the top of your code to use it. So now we can do

```
commas :: [String] -> String
commas = intercalate ", "
```

So we can display an individual Film, then use that to display the list of films.

```
showFilm :: Film -> String
showFilm (title,cast,year,fans) = commas [title, commas cast, show year, show (length fans)]
```

and we could write

```
showDatabase :: Database -> String
showDatabase fs = intercalate "\n" [showFilm f | f<-fs]
```

but it would be nicer to do

```
showDatabase :: Database -> String
showDatabase = unlines.map showFilm
```

because you just want to use `showFilm` on each of the films, and then `unlines` which just means `intercalate "\n"` anyway, but is easier on the eye.

```
> putStrLn $ showDatabase testDatabase
Casino Royale, Daniel Craig, Eva Green, Judi Dench, 2006, 5
Cowboys & Aliens, Harrison Ford, Daniel Craig, Olivia Wilde, 2011, 6
Catch Me If You Can, Leonardo DiCaprio, Tom Hanks, 2002, 9
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it now compiles, but what do I enter to invoke the function to run?

[Film] -> String -> String

What [Film] to I enter, and what String do I enter to output a string?

Comment: That has helped me alot, thank you very much! But one last question. I'm running this code in a WinGHCI environement and it does not implement the "\n" functions..Is this because it has to be in an i/o environment?

Comment: @user2240649 I'm testing it in WinGHCi actually. What error are you getting?

Comment: Oh - do you mean it shows `\n` instead of starting a newline? That's why I'm doing `putStrLn $`. It turns the String into a program that prints it, replacing `\n` with an actual newline. Was that the problem?

Comment: @user2240649 I'd like to be cheeky and say that you can say "that has helped" with the up arrow, and "this is the answer I needed" with the tick!  :)

Comment: Yeah exactly, it shows the \n instead for example:                                             

"\nCasino Royale, Daniel Craig, Eva Green, Judi Dench, 2006, 5\nCowboys & Aliens, Harrison Ford, Daniel Craig, Olivia Wilde, 2011, 6\nCatch Me If You Can, Leonardo DiCaprio, Tom Hanks, 2002, 9\nMamma Mia!, Meryl Streep, Pierce Brosnan, 2008, 6\nSaving Private Ryan, Tom Hanks, Matt Damon, 1998, 6\nLife of Pi, Suraj Sharma, 2012, 8........."

Comment: @user2240649 Yup - do `putStrLn $ showDatabase testDatabase` or if you prefer `putStrLn (showDatabase testDatabase)`